# String manipulation in python udf for pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to code with below use case, but stuck how to manipulate for a certain requirement in python

requirement is when we receive a string, if it has AM or PM, we have to extract the integers like 1130AM, my output should be 1130. if contains U in between the integers like, 1130U230AM, i have to extract the numeric values before and after U and multiply them. i coded for the 1st use case of extracting the numbers, but when multiplying when it has an 'U' in the middle, i am not sure how to code it. Please help.

```
def test_func(val):
    val = str(val)
    x = re.compile("[A-Za-z]+".replace('.', '\.'), re.IGNORECASE)
    y = re.compile("[0-9,.]+".replace('.', '\.'), re.IGNORECASE)
    x_1 = re.search(x, val)
    y_1 = re.search(y, val)
try:
    if not re.search('[AM|PM]$', val):
        return ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use udf for this case in spark, As **udf's are slow**.

Instead use spark inbuilt functions **`when+otherwise`** and **`regexp_extract,regexp_repla`ce** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample dataset
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1130AM',),('1130PM',),('1130U230AM',),('1130UAM',)],['tim_val'])

#using rlike we are matching if string has u or am/pm then caluculating new_col value    
df.withColumn("new_col",when(lower(col("tim_val")).rlike("(u)(.\\d+)"),\
    (regexp_extract(col("tim_val"),"(.*)(?i)(u)(.\\d+)",1)) * (regexp_extract(col("tim_val"),"(.*)(?i)(u)(.\\d+)",3))).\
when(lower(col("tim_val")).rlike("(?i)(u|am|pm)"),regexp_replace(col('tim_val'),'(?i)(u|am|pm)','')).\
otherwise('No')).\
show()

#+----------+--------+
#|   tim_val| new_col|
#+----------+--------+
#|    1130AM|    1130|
#|    1130PM|    1130|
#|1130U230AM|259900.0|
#|   1130UAM|    1130|
#+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Hello, if i have a column value as 1130UAM, it is not returning NULL, because of the 3rd group doesnt have any digits. do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have written this without using Regular Expressions, as from my experience they can be very difficult to understand sometimes.

```py
def extract_value(val):
    val = val[:-2]                        # remove AM or PM from end of val

    if 'U' in val:
        val = val.split('U')              # split into the two numbers
        val = int(val[0]) * int(val[1])   # multiply integer values
    else:
        val = int(val)                    # convert string to integer

    return val


value_to_extract = '1130U230AM'

output = extract_value(value_to_extract)
```

The value stored in `output`, in this case, will be 259900, which is the answer to 1130 * 230. This is a simple script and can definitely be improved if needed.